# iPhone: Use apple sample code AVCam to open new view controller after capturing video

Tags: iphone

I am using the apple sample code AVCam for capturing video

But i want to navigate to another view after pressing stop capturing video button

But i am unable to do this

Please suggest me the proper way to do this task

I am doing the follwing coding in  AVCam sample code method

```
- (void)captureManagerRecordingFinished:(AVCamCaptureManager *)captureManager
{
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^(void) 
    {

        [[self recordButton] setTitle:@"Record"];
        [[self recordButton] setEnabled:YES];

    });

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NextViewController *test=[[NextViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];

}
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong or any other way to do this task

Answer (score 2):

AVCam does not implement a NavigationController out of the box so pushing view controllers will not work.

However, it's not hard to do it

Open MainWindow.xib
Add a navigation Controller item just bellow Window and make sure that Cam View Controller is a child of the Navigation Controller - see the following image:
[image]

Right click on the Window item and make sure the rootViewController item is linked to the NavigationController, not to the Cam View Controller
[image]

Compile and run - pushing the view controller should now work.